# Rename [g-suite] to [google-workspace]

Tags: discussion, tags

Google has rebranded G Suite as Google Workspace. Please rename [g-suite](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/g-suite) to [google-workspace](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-workspace).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done

```
updating post history, 410 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 330 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
Target tag 'google-workspace' doesn't exist, renaming 'g-suite' to 'google-workspace'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [google-workspace] and [g-suite] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
21 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
49 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym g-suite -> google-workspace was approved!
```