# Rename [g-suite-administrator] to [google-workspace-administrator] or [google-workspace-admin-help]

Tags: discussion, tags

Please rename [g-suite-administrator](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/g-suite-administrator) to [google-workspace-administrator](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-workspace-administrator) or `google-workspace-admin-help`.

Comment: Please add more details regarding `...administrator` Vs. `...admin-help`

Comment: Related: [Rename \[g-suite\] to \[google-workspace\]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4782/88163)

Comment: @Rubén : https://support.google.com/a/answer/6208960?hl=en

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Both are same. We can have any.